# How to create multiple square matrices given a vector dimension in R

Tags: r

I would like to create multiple square matrices filled with 1, given the dimension of each matrix. The dimension information is stored in the vector, e.g, `c(4,11,5,9,51,34,11,28,47,6)`. How can I use `matrix(1,nrow,ncol)` to do this in R?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: What exactly are the dimensions? Does 4 mean a square matrix of 4 rows and columns or does every two elements stand for the nrow and ncol of the matrix ?

Comment: `lapply(dims, function(x) matrix(1,nrow=x,ncol=x))` (`dims` is the dimensions vector).

Comment: Thanks, that is what I expected

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list of matrices using:

```
dim.vec = c(4,11,5,9,51,34,11,28,47,6)
matrix.list = list() 

for(i in 1:length(dim.vec)){
  matrix.list[[i]] = matrix(1, dim.vec[i], dim.vec[i])
}

matrix.list
```

Comment: This is really just a less good version of the `lapply` approach that @nicola already showed in comments